# Auth.Token must be a "User" instance Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This error occurs when I try to login using the endpoint this endpoint api/auth/user.
ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('username', 'Kdot'), ('password', '123456')])": "AuthToken.user" must be a "User" instance.
Below is the urls

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .api import RegisterAPI, LoginAPI, UserAPI
from knox import views as knox_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth', include('knox.urls')),
    path('api/auth/register', RegisterAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/login', LoginAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/user', UserAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/auth/logout', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout')
]
```

Here is the api.py file

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer


# Register API
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "User": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "Token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


# Login API
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        _, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
        return Response({
            "User": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "Token": token
        })


# Get User API
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Below is the serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')


# Register Serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['username'],
            validated_data['email'],
            validated_data['password']
        )
        return user


# Login Serializer
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Username or Password")
```

Please can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hey Richard, I am late, but were you able to get the issue resolved? I am stuck at the same junction. please reply if you can

Comment: Hi Richard, seconding @user3521180 as I too am having the same issue. If either of you have resolved it would be great to hear! Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user3521180 still i have this can you please guide to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView, UpdateAPIView, DestroyAPIView
# from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser, AllowAny
# from knox.views import LoginView as KLView
from rest_framework import generics
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import RegistrationSerializers, LoginSerializer, UserSerializer
from .models import NewEmployeeProfile


class UserRegisterView(ListCreateAPIView):
    create_queryset = NewEmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializers
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        newUser = serializer.save()
        token = AuthToken.objects.create(newUser)[1]
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(newUser, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": token
        })
        # return Response(data={"status": "OK", "message": serializer.data, "token": token}
        #                 , status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class loginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)  # Load request body to serializer
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)  # Validate data in serializer and raise an error if one is found

        user = serializer.validated_data  # Get the validated data from the serializer
        token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]  # Create an Authentication Token for the user

        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,  # Get serialized User data
            "token": token
        })
```